# The sql has repeated query “in query” but faster than once in query?

Tags: mysql

mysql versin is 5.7,

```
SELECT distinct(t.id),
               t.sys_user_id,
               t.update_time
FROM institute_student t
         inner join institute_student_campus student_campus on student_campus.student_id = t.id
WHERE t.deleted = 0
  AND t.birth_country_id = 9
  AND t.type = 'FINISHED'
  AND t.gender = 6

  and t.id in (SELECT distinct s_alert.student_id FROM institute_student_alert_welfare s_alert inner join institute_alert_welfare alert on s_alert.alert_welfare_id=alert.id and alert.type='Alert')

  and student_campus.campus_id in (1, 2, 17, 18, 19, 20)
ORDER by t.update_time desc
LIMIT 15;
```

spend 4.25sec,

```
SELECT distinct(t.id),
               t.sys_user_id,
               t.update_time
FROM institute_student t
         inner join institute_student_campus student_campus on student_campus.student_id = t.id
WHERE t.deleted = 0
  AND t.birth_country_id = 9
  AND t.type = 'FINISHED'
  AND t.gender = 6

  and t.id in (SELECT distinct s_alert.student_id FROM institute_student_alert_welfare s_alert inner join institute_alert_welfare alert on s_alert.alert_welfare_id=alert.id and alert.type='Alert')
  and t.id in (SELECT distinct s_alert.student_id FROM institute_student_alert_welfare s_alert inner join institute_alert_welfare alert on s_alert.alert_welfare_id=alert.id and alert.type='Alert')

  and student_campus.campus_id in (1, 2, 17, 18, 19, 20)
ORDER by t.update_time desc
LIMIT 15;
```

spend 0.02sec.

The only diff is the double "in query" sql as below.

```
and t.id in (SELECT distinct s_alert.student_id FROM institute_student_alert_welfare s_alert inner join institute_alert_welfare alert on s_alert.alert_welfare_id=alert.id and alert.type='Alert')
```

Anyone can tell me why? Thanks :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q452r.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3EIj.png

Comment: As in the screenshots above

Comment: Show plans for both queries. Check that the output is not cached.

Comment: Hi Akina, I don't understand, can you give me more details, thank you very much.

Comment: 1) Execute both queries with additional `SQL_NO_CACHE` (see [SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for details). Does the difference remains unchanged? 2) Provide execution plans (see [EXPLAIN Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) for details).

Comment: Hi Akina, this is the explain. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/758Dy.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWOqc.png

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function